# Download files from storage is not working?

Tags: php, laravel

Actually my task is when I select from-date and to-date using date picker and then I click download button, select the id from orders table between dates and check invoice->id is matching with files in storage folder. If files are matched create zip and download.

I can zipped but download is not working.

[image: Click Here for firebug console result]

**export.blade.php**

```
<button class="btn btn-success dateDifference" role="button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download </button>

<script>
        $(".dateDifference").on("click", function() {
        var fromDate = $(".dateFrom").val();
        var toDate   = $(".dateTo").val();
        $.post('{{ route('exportInvoiceDownload') }}', {fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate}, function(response){
            //alert(response);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/export/download/invoices',  [
        'as' => 'exportInvoiceDownload', 'uses' => 'BookingController@downloadInvoices'
    ]);
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function downloadInvoices(Request $request)
    {
        $fromDateReplace     = str_replace('/', '-', $request->fromDate);
        $fromDate            = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fromDateReplace));
        $toDateReplace       = str_replace('/', '-', $request->toDate);
        $toDate              = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($toDateReplace));
        $archive_name = storage_path('app') . '/invoice_archive/Rechnung_'.$fromDate.'_'.$toDate.'.zip';
        $orders = Booking::select('invoice_id')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate, $toDate])
            ->get();
        if (count($orders) > 0 ) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open($archive_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {

                foreach ($orders as $order) {
                    $file = storage_path('app') . '/invoice_archive/test-'.$order->invoice_id.'.pdf';
                    if (file_exists($file)) {
                        $zip->addFile($file, 'test-'.$order->invoice_id.'.pdf');
                    }
                }
                $zip->close();
                $headers = [
                    'Pragma'                    => 'public',
                    'Expires'                   => 0,
                    'Content-Type'              => 'application/octet-stream',
                    'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename=\"test_'.$fromDate.'_'.$toDate.'.zip\"',
                    'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary'
                ];
                if (file_exists($archive_name)) {
                    return response()->download($archive_name, 'test_'.$fromDate.'_'.$toDate.'.zip', $headers) /*->deleteFileAfterSend(TRUE)*/;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you are calling this route with ajax, if that's true than download won't work in this case, you need traditional post request because ajax binary response will not open download popup in browser so instead of ajax just submit the form as browser default or make it get request and open it in new browser tab then it will consider content-dispostion header and download popup will appear.